# Shopify - data model

Tags: data-modeling, shopify

One of my customer requested some changes on shopify site. She sell pictures and she would like to start offer the frames.

But the whole administration of the frames will be so complicated that I know now, that I will need to somehow extend the data model, because I will need to store some additional relations.

So my question is: Is it somehow possible to store any kind of data by shopify API? Like create a new entities with custom attributes etc. I was searching through the API documentation but I was not able to find any solution.

Second question is: Would it be possible to solve this problem by Embedded App? Thats mean, that I will develop the whole administration part as a small application and then embed it to the shopify? Will it be possible then join data from shopify storage and my database through Shopify API?

Is there some example for this scenario?

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: yes, is posible. you have to create a third party app using the api, and you can set the aditional data in the order properties

Answer (score 0):

I built a Shopify store selling frames when Shopify first came out. That shop still sells many many frames. There was not even a Shopify API back then. Still, it was possible to do it with 100% client-side code. You simply price each frame in units. For example, $1 per inch. Client-side you collect the frame size as length x width, and come up with the total inches needed, and there is your quantity. Use mm, cm whatever units work for you. You can even get fancy if you're good, and work in mats, backing, and types of glass, all with one add to cart click.